# How to compile single c# file on mac console using mono?

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I want to compile a simple "hello world" on mac console.
I have made dmcs symbolic on /usr/local/bin/.

```
using System; 

class Hello 
{ 
      static void Main(){ 
    　Console.WriteLine("Hello,World"); 
    } 
}
```

But after typing

```
dmcs Hello.cs
```

I get Hello.exe

.exe file seems a Windows file.

So, How to compile single c# file on mac console using mono?

Comment: Do you not then just go mono Hello.exe ? http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JamesSugrue is right in your comment, you need to run the project using the mono framework using the described command line.

```
mono Hello.exe
```

The mono compiler creates files with extensions just like csc would on Windows. The difference is that on Mac and Linux the extension really is a suggestion about what is inside, rather than a rule like it is on Windows.